# Fabric, Python - Change env programmatically

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a way to change the current env programmatically when using Fabric for deployment?

What I would like to do, is perform a task on all my environments with in one call. Looping though the envs, and calling the same task.

for instance:

```
def live():
    env.host = ['123.123.123.123']

def dev():
    env.host = ['321.321.321.321']

environments = ['live', 'dev']

def backup_db():
    run('mysqldump etc ..' % env)

def backup_all_dbs():
    for environment in environments:
        env = new_env(environment)
        backup_db
```

and then run

```
fab backup_all_dbs
```

but I don't know how to instantiate the env on the fly, and actually change the current env to a new one in code.

I don't think just calling the env function e.g dev() or live() is enough as there are other things in the current env dict if you inspect it.

I can't see anything in the docs about this, perhaps the env can only be created once from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the best way to use Fabric, in terms of executing the same command across multiple hosts. The better way looks like this:

```
from fabric.api import env, run, task

env.hosts = ['123.123.123.123', '213.213.213.213']

@task
def uname():
  run('uname -a')
```

You'll want to reference the [How host lists are constructed](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/execution.html#how-host-lists-are-constructed) section of the docs for more info.

Comment: HI - thanks for that. I already have multiple hosts per env set up. However that is not what I want to achieve (or what I was asking). I also don't think it's unreasonable to ask all your environments to execute the same task on all of their hosts, eg backup their current DB if that's what you want to do.

Comment: That's not how Fabric works though: you're not "asking" your "environments" to execute the same task. There is only one environment, and it's a global value. You also asked how to run the same task on all hosts - and that's exactly what the example I provided does. Did you even run the script above to see its output?

Comment: No I didn't run your example, because I can see what it is does and it's not what I am asking. If you do not Know the answer to my question, that's totally fine. What I am asking is very clear technically - can you change the global value of 'env' programmatically during run time ? just for giggles.

Comment: The answer the that is yes. For example, the env.host_string is a value that users frequently set and alter during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
hosts = [ { 
    'h':'any_ip', 
    'u':'any_user', 
    'k':'path_to_key'
    }, ... ]

for instance in hosts:
    instance_in_test = instance.h

    print("Setting things for " + instance_in_test)

    env.user = instance.u
    env.hosts = [ instance_in_test ]
    env.host_string = instance_in_test
    env.key_filename = instance.k

    print("Doing things on: %s" % (instance_in_test))

    run('ls -la')
    sudo('mkdir /etc/foo')

    print("Done")
```

It will loop through hosts included in the array of objects describing  configurations.

Comment: yes, not disimilar to my example. However there is a lot more to and Env than just those attributes. What I want to know is - how to initialise an env programmatically. Changing the env.user is not enough.

Comment: you can do everything you need to do (shown in the answer as the lines between both informative `print()`) to set your environment inside a function, or reformulate your question in such a way it actually represents what you mean. Anyway you do, good luck!